# ASP.NET Core Microservices

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, microservices, docker-container

I am creating microservices using docker and asp.net core 2. I have created 2 microservices and a web api. I am trying to call the microservice endpoint from the web api using HttpClient. Below is the web api controller code

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAsync()
    {
        
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var data = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:8081/api/values");

        return new string[] { "apigateway-value1", "apigateway-value2" };
    }
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file where the microservice I am trying to call is specified.

```
microserviceone:

image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}microserviceone
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: MicroserviceOne/Dockerfile
ports: 
- "8082:80"
```

This the microservice Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base    
WORKDIR /app    
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build    
WORKDIR /src    
COPY MicroserviceOne/MicroserviceOne.csproj MicroserviceOne/    
RUN dotnet restore MicroserviceOne/MicroserviceOne.csproj    
COPY . .    
WORKDIR /src/MicroserviceOne    
RUN dotnet build MicroserviceOne.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish    
RUN dotnet publish MicroserviceOne.csproj -c Release -o /app    

FROM base AS final    
WORKDIR /app    
COPY --from=publish /app .    
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MicroserviceOne.dll"]
```

The problem is I am getting an error "System.Net.Http.CurlException: Couldn't connect to server". From the command prompt if I try to access the same endpoint using the command

```
curl -X GET -H Content-Type: application/json  http://localhost:808/api/values
```

I am getting the data. I really don't know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using hostname/ipaddress instead of localhost. The 'localhost' represents the current container.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use docker run command with "-p" to bind container port with the port on the host. The below command uses 5003 port of the host and bind to to port 80 of the container named "myaspapp" running your asp.net core app.

```
docker run -p 5003:80 myaspapp
```

Then you can open the app on the browser with using **https://localhost:50003** url and can also use curl.

You can refer this - [Create first ASP.NET Core App in a Docker Container](https://www.yogihosting.com/docker-aspnet-core-app/)